# Design of a data structure that can search over objects with 2 attributes

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I'm trying to think of a way to desing a data structure that I can efficiently insert to, remove from and search in it.

The catch is that the search function is getting a similar object as input, with 2 attributes, and I need to find an object in my dataset, such that both the 1st and 2nd of the object in my dataset are equal to or bigger than the one in search function's input.

So for example, if I send as input, the following object:

```
object[a] = 9; object[b] = 14
```

Then a valid found object could be:

```
object[a] = 9; object[b] = 79
```

but not:

```
object[a] = 8; object[b] = 28
```

Is there anyway to store the data such that the search complexity is better than linear?

EDIT:
I forgot to include in my original question. The search has to return the smallest possible object in the dataset, by multipication of the 2 attributes.

Meaning that the value of `object[a]*object[b]` of an object that fits the original condition, is smaller than any other object in the dataset that also fits.

Comment: The question is obscure. As far as I understand, using TWO MAX HEAP provides constant time complexity for search.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include that it has to be the smallest possible value in the DB. I'll edit it now.

Comment: If the condition is `object[a]*object[b]`, then why not sort on the condition? Or sort on `object[a]*(MAX_OF_TYPE_B+1) + object[b]` (assuming there's a data type large enough)?

Comment: What is maximum value that an attribute can take? In other words, is the space complexity  a concern in your situation?

Comment: Can the attribute be negative?

Comment: @CahitGungor: attributes cannot be negative. space complexity is a concern but there is no maximum for the attributes. The question is mainly in theoretical computer science.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to use `k-d tree` data structure, which is typically use to index k dimensional points. The search operation, like what you perform, requires `O(log n)` in average.

Comment: Pretty useless answer w/o an example or further explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This post may help when attributes are hierarchically linked like name, forename. For point in a 2D space k-d tree is more adapted as explain by [fajarkoe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24686896/1624376).

```
class Person {
   string name;
   string forename;
   ... other non key attributes
}
```

You have to write a comparator function which take two objects of class X as input and returns -1, 0 or +1 for <, = and > cases.

Libraries like [glibc()](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/), with [qsort()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/) and [bsearch](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/bsearch/) or more higher languages like Java and its [java.util.Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) class and [java.util.SortedMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) (implementation [java.util.TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)) as containers use comparators.

Other languages use equivalent concept.

The comparator method may be wrote followin your spec like:

```
int compare( Person left, Person right ) {
   if( left.name < right.name ) {
      return -1;
   }
   if( left.name > right.name ) {
      return +1;
   }
   if( left.forename < right.forename ) {
      return -1;
   }
   if( left.forename > right.forename ) {
      return +1;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

[Complexity of qsort()](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort)

> Quicksort, or partition-exchange sort, is a sorting algorithm
>   developed by Tony Hoare that, on average, makes O(n log n) comparisons
>   to sort n items. In the worst case, it makes O(n2) comparisons, though
>   this behavior is rare. Quicksort is often faster in practice than
>   other O(n log n) algorithms.[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24686896/1624376) Additionally, quicksort's sequential
>   and localized memory references work well with a cache. Quicksort is a
>   comparison sort and, in efficient implementations, is not a stable
>   sort. Quicksort can be implemented with an in-place partitioning
>   algorithm, so the entire sort can be done with only O(log n)
>   additional space used by the stack during the recursion.[2](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/)

[Complexity of bsearch()](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)

> If the list to be searched contains more than a few items (a dozen,
>   say) a binary search will require far fewer comparisons than a linear
>   search, but it imposes the requirement that the list be sorted.
>   Similarly, a hash search can be faster than a binary search but
>   imposes still greater requirements. If the contents of the array are
>   modified between searches, maintaining these requirements may even
>   take more time than the searches. And if it is known that some items
>   will be searched for much more often than others, and it can be
>   arranged so that these items are at the start of the list, then a
>   linear search may be the best.

Comment: That would still be linear complexity. I will have to iterate this on each object in my dataset. I'm more interested in implementing some kind of a smart data structure, so I won't have to iterate over all off them, only over log(n) or sqroot(n) or anything better than linear.

Comment: @Tom: But a simple [AVL tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) will give you O(log n) complexity for insertion, deletion, and search if you apply a custom comparator.

Comment: The problem is with the comperator. It will not work. there very may be that some of the dataset entries have attribute A bigger and attribute B smaller, so with that implementation of the comparator, left is bigger then right, and right is also bigger then left.

Comment: Also, the idea is not to use something from an existing code, this is why I didn't tag the question with any specific langauge

Comment: @JimMischel: as I said in the comment above, by what the comparison will the AVL tree base on? by the 1st attribute, the 2nd or the multiplication of the two?

Comment: Comparator edited, I think this post may help when attributes are hierachical like name, forename. For point in a 2D space k-d tree is more adapted.